axure problem with instructions that scroll me up when mouse enter or exit
I have problem in axure program that i put interaction on dynamic panel that when mouse enter will flip also when mouse exit will flip. So, the problem is when the mouse enter or exit the page move top the page. Some times it is work like i flip it 5 times and the 6th will back to top.
I tried to remove each part but it did not fix.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
